# Get the result of the sql query in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL Database setup.

[image]

When I execute in MySQL shell:

`"SELECT count(serverid) as num FROM servers WHERE owner_id = 1"`

it says:

```
+-----+
| num |
+-----+
|   4 |
+-----+
```

which is correct.
In php i want one variable having the value `4`.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cswebin', 'root', 'password');
 $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(serverid) as num FROM servers WHERE owner_id = :useruid");
$result = $statement->execute();
echo $result;
```

But this does not work. The `$result` does not have the value `4`. Can you help me with that lines that are missing here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at the [PHP PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) Specifically `bindValue()` [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) And `fetch()` [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: And on `fetch_*` functions of `PDO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you didn't bind your variable, so bind your variable using `->bindParam()` first. And second, use `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` to get the row from the result set.

So your code should be like this:

```
$useruid = <YOUR VALUE>;

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cswebin', 'root', 'password');
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(serverid) as num FROM servers WHERE owner_id = :useruid");
$statement->bindParam(':useruid', $useruid);
if($statement->execute()){
    $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $row['num'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the result after `execute()` the query. For example:

```
$result = $statement->execute()->fetchAll();
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$dt = $statement->execute();
$result = $dt->fetch();
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: `$result` will be an array so maybe you intended to do `print_r($result)`

Comment: Or `echo $result['num'];` maybe

Comment: ...or use list($result) = $dt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

Comment: Ok that will do I suppose.